# Warning: "throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()". throw;

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, etherscan

my question is if "THROW" is deprecated then what i have to put instead throw in the following solidity code ?

```
// This function creates Tokens  
     function createTokens() payable {
        if(isMinting == true){
            require(msg.value > 0);
            uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
            _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
            owner.transfer(msg.value);
        }
        else{
            throw;
        }
    }
```

so the code should look like this:

```
// This function creates Tokens  
 function createTokens() payable {
 require(isMinting == true && msg.value > 0);
 uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
 balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
 _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
 owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    else{
        throw;
    }
}
```

Or i have to delete the

`else{
     throw;`

last update:

```
function createTokens() payable public {
    if(isMinting == true){
       require(isMinting, "Not allowed");
       require(msg.value > 0, "No funds");
        uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    else{
        revert();
    }
```

thanks AK

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for an alternative of `throw`, you can use `revert` in the similar way. The `revert` function can be used to flag an error and revert the current call. As stated in solidity docs :

> Note
>
> There used to be a keyword called throw with the same semantics as
>   revert() which was deprecated in version 0.4.13 and removed in version
>   0.5.0.

From code point of view, you can use the `require` as below:

```
 function createTokens() payable {
        require(isMinting == true && msg.value > 0);
        uint256  tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
  }
```

So if `isMinting` is not equal to `true`, it will throw straight from there without making any changes in the state.

For more : https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions

Comment: Could you give me an example in the code please?
I am a beginner and I want to go the right way. and thanks A.K.

Comment: Hope edited answer helps.

Comment: delete `else` section as this is in functionality of `require` that it will throw if any one of the passed condition fails, use same code as i added in the answer.

Comment: Look if it's ok please and tell me if it's like that in my question, below last update

Comment: Answer updated. You can also use online solidity IDE remix : http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.js

Comment: @upracha in your recent update in question, you can remove `require(isMinting, "Not allowed");` Rest is fine, it will work in the same way

Comment: @upracha if it is solved you can mark it correct answer for community

Comment: sorry where can i mark correct answer i am new here

Comment: Click on 'right tick' on left top side of answer. Check other questions

Answer (score 0):

For your case and most cases you should use `require(isMinting, "Unallowed");`.
`require(false)` condition reverts the current call, i.e. storage changes are undone and msg.value is not transferred to the contract.

`throw` behavior is equivalent to `assert(false, "Reason")`, they will cause transaction fail and also waste all remaining gas, this reverts all the call stack.

Learn more about failing transactions using this example https://gist.github.com/3esmit/8954425d2ed0322505245803d6c045e4

`function createTokens() payable {
   require(isMinting, "Not allowed");
   require(msg.value > 0, "No funds");
   uint256 tokens = msg.value.div(100000000000000).mul(RATE);
   balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
   _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(tokens);
   owner.transfer(msg.value); 
}`

Comment: hello can you give me example with the code in my question please ?

Comment: edited answer with specific suggestion for your code.

Comment: i edit the question look below last updated, in remix this code dont show warnings, so please check and tell me if is good and you make some mistake in your answer, thanks

Comment: I cannot do the work for you. See if it compiles, if yes, test it. Consider installing embark framework and make test scripts.